# How can i set domain name in absolute url for imagefield drf?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Now if i get some data via swagger, ImageField looks like `http://api.some.com/media/picture.jpg`.
How can i change `http://api.some.com` to `https://api2.some.com` for all ImageField's i can get from my API?

Comment: you should install ssl on your api server and add nginx setting to redirect http to https then it will automatically send https image field url.

Comment: but can i change api to api2 for example. Can i build here my own domain name?

Comment: You can use the string formatting technique, right? @Oleksandr

Comment: yeap. In each serializer. But i'm more interested in all in one way